Vector tiles vs raster tiles when building a heatmap
Can heatmaps be generated and stored as a vector tile?
Based on the research I made, heat maps depend on density of features. And with vector tiles often we have the tiles simplified and features being merged together to reduce the size of it. So based on this we won't all the data for the heatmap except if we aggregated the data and had the features with their density. However with raster tiles we can add bands for features and assign a color with an alpha and with this features that overlaps will produce a darker shade of the color.
Based on this, are heatmaps better to be generated and stored as Raster tiles or we can do the same thing with vector tiles?

You seem to be confusing data processing and data presentation. Heatmaps should always be collected at the finest resolution at which they will be displayed. This has nothing to do with vector vs. raster tiles, which are presentation techniques (and somewhat subjective in application).
